# Java String delete part of string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a Java String like this

```
  "functional_type":"endpoint","configuration":[],"neighbours":{ "1": {"id":1,"name": "ep"}}},
```

And I wish to replace this part

```
"neighbours":{ "1": {
```

with another string. Moreover the number one is could be any number like for example `23` or `1903434` in order to have at the end this:

```
"functional_type":"endpoint","configuration":[],"filed":{"id":1,"name": "ep"}}},
```

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that replacing the string with two `{` with a string with only one `{` will make it no more possible to be parsed as JSON?

Comment: Yes, I know it! I use string instead JSON because my application uses string, but I have to necessity to replace this part of string.

Comment: You should be doing this at the object level via its API, not fiddling around with JSON encodings.

Comment: I know it, but I cannot do it. I must use the string.

Comment: I don't understand because it is wrong this regex ` "neighbours\":{\"[0-9]+\":{\"";`

Comment: The source string has spaces you're not accounting for.

Answer (score 0):

You should escape "{".

```
String s = "\"functional_type\":\"endpoint\",\"configuration\":[],\"neighbours\":{ \"1\": {\"id\":1,\"name\": \"ep\"}}},";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\"neighbours\":\\{ \"\\d+\": \\{", "\"filed\":{"));
```

result:

```
"functional_type":"endpoint","configuration":[],"filed":{"id":1,"name": "ep"}}},
```